# How do I get rid of the 'admin menu' you see when you right-click the Start button in Windows 10, via GP?

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

So I'm trying to lock down a set of lab computers, and you can't right-click anywhere on the Taskbar, via the Remove access to the context menus for the taskbar GP, but you can still right-click on the start button and get the following options:
Programs and Features, Power Options, Event Viewer, System, Device Manager, Network Connections, Disk Management, Computer Management, Command Prompt, Command Prompt (Admin), Task Manage, Control Panel, File Explorer, Search, Run and Shut down or sign out.
Any ideas for me?

Comment: You should be able to disable that menu with a group policy.  What has your researched on the subject shown?  Of course when I right click on my stat menu I don't even get those options, are you sure, its just a right click operation?

Comment: One way is to clear those WinX Group# folders.
http://www.allthingstechie.net/2015/09/disable-start-menu-winx-hidden-context.html

Comment: If you're on windows 10, ramhound, then you should get that menu. Even if you're a standard user.
w32sh, I've actually looked into that and, maybe I did it wrong, but it didn't hide anything :/

Answer (score 0):

Just delete all `GroupX` folders in:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX
```

after restarting Explorer.exe, there is no Win+X menu, anymore.

If you have a smart user, she could just add the GroupX folders and shortcuts within them back to `...\Windows\WinX`, so you also need to remove write-permissions for the user on that folder.

There may be a more official way, but this hack seems to work.

Comment: That may be true, and I appreciate the answer, but that doesn't solve the problem; I need to be able to do this via Group Policy to up to 200 computers/users and I'd rather not do that manually.

Comment: @Chris - Isn't it possible to delete folders with Group Policies? I haven't done much GP work for a while.